# 'check_tomcat.pl' plugin returning CRITICAL: /manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: tomcat, nagios

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm trying to use this plugin, check_tomcat.pl but it doesn't seem to be configured correctly.
Keeps returning the error:

```
CRITICAL: http://myhostname:8080/manager/status?XML=true HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

has anyone successfully implemented this nagios plugin?
the command I'm using is this:

```
./check_tomcat.pl -H {hostaddress} -p 8080 -a appname
```

Comment: Can you load http://myhostname:8080/manager/status?XML=true in a browser?  (Or is the question that it's substituting a different hostname?)

Comment: I can, but it comes up as a blank page. I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: It means the problem isn't check_tomcat.pl, or that the admin page it's referring to has moved.  The plugin is parsing the XML output on that page to return your results.

Comment: Any idea how to go about fixing it then?

Comment: when using wget on the same url, it is returning 404, however, when I access the URL from my browser, I just get a white page